# Is it possible to reuse value in MySQL SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have complex expression which I wish to reuse.

Below I had to write `Complex Expression` 2 times:

```
SELECT "Complex Expression" AS V, "Complex Expression" LIKE "%lex%" W
```

I would write

```
SELECT "Complex Expression" AS V, V LIKE "%lex%" W
```

but MySQL swears.

How to overcome?

Comment: Do you mean `WHERE V LIKE ...`? Not sure why you're selecting the result of a `LIKE` in the query itself. @vkp is right, you'll need to use a sub-query to do this, as a `SELECT` can work with the results of another `SELECT`.

Comment: Sub-queries are not allowed in views. I don't understand, why I need to use such heavy feature?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select * from (
   select "Complex Expression" AS V
   from table) AS subquery
where V like '%lex%'
```